# Where should a PHP framework be placed on a webserver?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, yii, directory-structure

Does anyone have an idea on where is it best to upload a PHP framework such as Yii, or CodeIgniter? Should I upload the files into a sub-directory within my website, or right into a root directory like the server's main public directory or public_html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like to create folder within my main directory to place the web application. Then point your domain name at the folder. This allows you to potentially host other web applications on the same hosting or have subdomains with seperate code.

```
#myapp.com
   => ../public_html/myapp/public/

#admin.myapp.com
   => ../public_html/myappadmin/public/

#myotherapp.com
   => ../public_html/myotherapp/public/
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's generally considered better practice to have the framework files / any database connection credentials outside of your webroot folder.  If your webserver ever were misconfigured in someway, you wouldn't want people to be able to browse all of your private credentials, your models, etc.

Here's a good article on how to do it:
[Yii Framework: moving-project-code-outside-of-webroot-plus-multiple-project-support](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/116/moving-project-code-outside-of-webroot-plus-multiple-project-support/)

I generally move my protected folder out of my webroot folder.  I haven't worried about the runtime folder, as I just ignore that in my .gitignore file.